# breeze server side cache support

Tags: breeze

Is it possible to use server side cache with breeze?
Currently using NH and have second and first level cache setup but breeze always loads the entities from the DB

If anyone already did something like that please send some code examples

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the [NHibernate Query Cache](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#performance-querycache) as described in the [doc](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#performance-querycache), then create your queries as cacheable queries.

In a Breeze/WebAPI application, you would typically create an [NHContext](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider.NH/NHContext.cs) instance for a Session, then use it from your WebAPI controller to create queries:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers()
    {
        return myContext.GetQuery<Customer>(true);  // true means cacheable
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Order> Orders()
    {
        return myContext.GetQuery<Order>("orderRegion");  // region name means cacheable
    }
```